# DropDownList Selected Index change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using DropDownList inside Updatepanel with its autopost back property set to true,
its working fine except when it has SelectedValue=0(ie SelectedIndex=0)

here's my drop down list

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFilter" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" Style="width: 168px;
            border: none;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddComapanyFilter_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Flagged" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="New" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is my SelectedIndexChangedEvent

```
protected void ddComapanyFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddComapanyFilter.SelectedValue == "0")//All
    {
       //code
    }
    else if (ddComapanyFilter.SelectedValue == "1")//Flagged
    {
       //code
    }
    else if (ddComapanyFilter.SelectedValue == "2")//New
    {
       //code
    }          
}
```

When I select New or Flagged it works fine, but when I again select All,it don't do any thing,I have tried debugging it,in case of All its not hitting the code.

I tried by replacing my drop down code with this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddFilter" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" Style="width: 168px;
                                border: none;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddComapanyFilter_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                AutoPostBack="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Flagged" Value="2" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="New" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Now When I am selecting Flagged,after selecting New or All, its not hitting

Comment: While Debugging, when you select 'All' what is the value coming in ddCompanyFilter.SelectedValue??

Comment: What about setting start `Value="0"` to `Value="1"` and then 2, 3 ?

Comment: So, you first select Flagged/New and it works, and then select All after that and it doesnt do anythin? Or are you trying to select All while All was selected n the first place

Comment: When I am selecting All, its not hitting the code

Comment: @zey I tried your solution,but still same issue

Comment: @astander I am trying to select All, when Flagged or New is selected

Comment: So , what about `ddComapanyFilter.Text == "All"` ?

Comment: @zey may be it will work, but  I am trying to select All, when Flagged or New is selected. in that case its not hitting the code

Comment: One of Flagged or New is selected ? **OR** ,  both Flagged and New is selected ?

Comment: Offcourse anyone of them,either Flagged or NEW

Comment: May be `Selected="True"` causing the problem. Try defining the default Selected=True Value in the (!IsPostBack) Condition inside PageLoad method and remove it from ASPX code. i.e `ddCompanyFilter.SelectedValue = "1"`

Comment: Yes selected="true" causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in dropdownlist, always first list item doesn't fire that's why you can add a dummy listitem at the beginning like "Select.." or what ever you want to make it work

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFilter" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" Style="width: 168px;
            border: none;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddComapanyFilter_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="whatever" value=""></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Flagged" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="New" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```